# anyone know how to install stanford menu?

Tags: eclipse, karel

I have tried to access the Stanford repository through eclipse that you indicate in the previous answers and I have not been able to access since it appears that it is not on that page. My question is, where could I find the repository to be able to use the tools in the Stanford menu? The operating system I have is mac os, and the program I use is eclipse. Accessing help and installing new software and entering the Stanford page is where you can't find the eclipse plugin! I am attaching the image where the instructions to install the stanford plugin appear, the page where to add the repository is obsolete. What I wanted to ask is if anyone knows which page the plugin is located to add it to eclipse?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have tried to download the plugin from the stanford website by entering the stanford url, but it tells me that it does not exist and I cannot install the stanford menu in eclipse to work with karel